# Modal for multiple images:

Tags: javascript, html

I looked around at the answers on such questions and couldn't understand anything. Deeply appreciated if you can help:

I have some pictures on a website. I want the modal to work such that when a picture is clicked it appears in a larger size.

The Problem: The code only works for the first image. When I click in the second image, nothing happens. I HAVE looked around and seen some answers pointing out that having the same id for different images is the problem but I couldn't understand how to fix this issue.

The Other Problem: I have JS code for a slide show and JS code for the modal. However, if the code for the modal comes in first, the code for the slideshow doesnt work, and vice-versa

I copied the code from W3Schools:

HTML HERE

```
                            <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img id="myImg" src="assets/img/work/amigurumi/cerdo/main.JPG" alt="Cerdito" width="360">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
                <p>Cerdito 1</p>
            </div>





<div class="col-lg-4">
                            <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img id="myImg" src="assets/img/work/amigurumi/cerdo/P1140064.JPG" alt="Problema con imagen" width="360">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
                <p>Cerdito 2</p>
            </div>
```

JS HERE - Note I've put down the JS code for the modal and for a slideshow because I'm having a connected problem. JS only works for the code which appears first (so if the slide show code is after the modal code, slide show doesnt work...)

```
// IMAGE MODAL DAVID Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


//Slideshow DAVID

var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Your `HTML ` codes aren't readable though. there is a ID called `mymodal` right? You have to make that unique for all images. otherwise, it will open only one image.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help.

Comment: <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

So should I have for each image "myModal1" "myModal2" etc?

But then, wouldnt I have to change the Java Script too? How?

Comment: Yes @david There you are.

Comment: How about the JS?

Comment: Well the thing is you have to use unique id on both places, I mean `<!-- The Modal --> <div id="myModal1" class="modal"> So should I have for each image "myModal1"` and you have to move this way

Comment: Both modal id need to be same like modal1 modal1 then modal2 modal2 i hope you understand

Comment: As your images are opening up then I think JS is fine. You just need to work there to load modals properly.

Comment: I understand the solution is simple but I'm still not sure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

In the name of your modal question you must like this solution, I imagine. I posted an answer here to a similar question few days ago. Go to :

[Add next and previous buttons when the I open the modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275148/add-next-and-previous-buttons-when-the-i-open-the-modal/44278476?noredirect=1#comment75566691_44278476)

Good luck